# PHP cp permissions issue

Tags: php, shell, permissions

**PHP Script (restore.php):**

```
var_dump( get_current_user());
var_dump( shell_exec( " cp /var/www/bkp/* /var/www/html 2>&1 " ));
```

**When script is accessed in browser:**

```
string(6) "apache"
string(115) "cp: cannot create regular file `/var/www/html/227.png': Permission denied cp: cannot remove `/var/www/html/234.png' Permission denied "
```

**Console:**

```
cd /var/www/html
sudo -u apache touch test.txt
ls test.txt
  -> test.txt
sudo -u rm 234.png -f
ls 234.png
  -> ls: 234.png: No such file or directory
sudo -u apache php restore.php
ls 234.png
  -> 234.png
```

Can anyone explain why I am getting permission issues in my php script when run in browser?

Comment: How is this question off topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that Apache is running as the `apache` user? `get_current_user()` returns the owner of the script. You would think Apache would be running as `apache` but maybe it's not.

You can get the name of the process owner with this:

```
$processUser = posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid());
print $processUser['name'];
```

Comment: You're right. I didn't know the difference. It's run as `daemon` user. How do I change it to run as another user'

Comment: In `/etc/apache2/envvars` you can edit the APACHE_RUN_USER and APACHE_RUN_GROUP settings to the user and group of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

check that /var/www/ owner is www-data( the user of apache web server ),and he have the permission to red & write  .